# Is there a word meaning "an unwanted eponym"?

Tags: single-word-requests, eponyms

An eponym is one way to eternal (if posthumous) fame. But is there a word meaning an eponym someone would sooner not have? (One would presume that Captain Charles *Boycott*, Mr Justice *Lynch*, and Patrick *Hooligan* would not appreciate their undying notoriety.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Robusto has it with *negative eponym*...I would only add this usage:

> The practice originated with the infamously eponymous Charles Hooligan...

Comment: @Robustu, @Chris, thank you. I think I'd go with "infamously emponymous"...

Answer (score 2):

I would probably just call it a *negative eponym* (as it was recently used in an article about [Breitbartling](http://sigmundcarlandalfred.wordpress.com/2010/08/11/breitbarting/), in which the author also refers to "borking"). But that still doesn't convey the sense of the eponym being unwanted, which I don't believe can be expressed yet in a single word. I think you can assume that *negative* implies unwanted, but that will never be true 100% of the time.